# Running a cmd command in Python

Tags: python-3.x, batch-file, cmd

I am having a problem that I have been spending quite a lot of time on. I have a few lines of code that I run through a bat file, that I would like to run from a Python script instead. This is so that I can feed in variables and create the cmd string throug Python code.

The code is used to run Tableau bridge client to sync a data extract. This is the code and it works when I run it from a BAT file:

```
@echo off
cd C:\Program Files\Tableau\Tableau 10.3\bin
tableau refreshextract --server https://dub01.online.tableau.com --username "username" --password "password" --site "sitename" --project "project name" --datasource "datasource name" --source-username sql_backend_username --source-password sql_backend_password
```

I understand that the first line sets the working directory to the folder where Tableau is installed. And the second line does the refreshing.

I have been trying to make this work in Python by just doing something like this:

```
import os

os.chdir("C:\\Program Files\\Tableau\\Tableau 10.3\\bin")
os.system("tableau -cmd_string_from_above
```

but all that this does is run the Tableau client, and not the process running the extract. I have been looking at some examples using popen but all of that code is so complex that I dont understand how it actually works.

Hope someone can help me out.

Answer (score 0):

If it works as a bat file, try running that from python.

```
os.system("start mybatch.bat")
```

Comment: I have been doing that, and that works to. But I need it to be able to feed in the different variables through Python code before running it. This is used to update multiple data sources for multiple projects and sites. So I dont want to create one BAT file for each, and then having to manually change variables like usernames and passwords in all the files when they change.

Comment: Consider using arguments when calling your batch. You can pass them through python in the os.system call, then read them in the batch file

Comment: Could you give me some hints about the syntax for that? I did create a bat file named test.bat with the following code
@echo off

echo %1
echo %2
echo %3

PAUSE

and I  can run it from a terminal ok. But when I try to run it through Python using os like this:

import os
os.system("test.bat 1 2 3") 

is does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you look at the module [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html)

as and example:

```
subprocess.call(["C:\\Program Files\\Tableau\\Tableau 10.3\\bintableau", "refreshextract", "etc. etc."])
```

a simpler example:

```
from subprocess import call
call(["ping", "localhost"])
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so building on the code/methods other sugested here I did manage to get it working. It might be kind if a "hacky" solution, but it looks like it is working ok. Here is the example

```
import json
import os
import subprocess

def refresh_extract(project_name, datasource_name):

    #Json file containing most of the variables used
    params = json.load(open('all_paths.json'))

    server = params['tableau']['server']
    username = params['tableau']['username']
    password = params['tableau']['password']
    site = params['tableau']['site']
    source_username = params['tableau']['source-username']
    source_password = params['tableau']['source-password']

    filepath = "Path to bat file that is called"

    executable = os.path.join(filepath, 'tableau_refresh.bat')

    #Set the working dir to dir where tableau files used for the call is stored, this is the "hacky" part, needed for the bat to find tableau
    os.chdir("C:\\Program Files\\Tableau\\Tableau 10.3\\bin")

    p = subprocess.Popen([executable, '%s' %server, '%s' %username, '%s' %password, '%s' %site, '%s' %project_name, '%s' %datasource_name, '%s' %source_username, '%s' %source_password])

    return 0



if __name__ == "__main__":

project_name = "project_name"
datasource_name = "data_source_name"

run = refresh_extract(project_name, datasource_name)
```

Thanks a  lot to everyone that helped me figure it out!

This is the code for the bat file just in case it could help someone else

```
@echo off


#this seems not to be working, therefore I set the working did using 
#os.chdir
cd C:\Program Files\Tableau\Tableau 10.3\bin

tableau refreshextract --server %1 --username %2 --password %3 --site %4 --
project %5 --datasource %6 --source-username %7 --source-password %8
PAUSE
```